# jQuery setting first() but multiple times

Tags: jquery

hi all so i have for example 4 sets of lists and want to set active class for the first of each section but at the moment on my JS of course just sets the first one and does not do the others, any ideas how i can sort so does first for each DL?

markup example:

```
<div class="faqs">
  <dl>
    <dd><div class="content"></div></dd>
    <dd><div class="content"></div></dd>
    <dd><div class="content"></div></dd>
    <dd><div class="content"></div></dd>
  </dl>
</div>

<div class="faqs">
  <dl>
    <dd><div class="content"></div></dd>
    <dd><div class="content"></div></dd>
    <dd><div class="content"></div></dd>
    <dd><div class="content"></div></dd>
  </dl>
</div>

<div class="faqs">
  <dl>
    <dd><div class="content"></div></dd>
    <dd><div class="content"></div></dd>
    <dd><div class="content"></div></dd>
    <dd><div class="content"></div></dd>
  </dl>
</div>

<div class="faqs">
  <dl>
    <dd><div class="content"></div></dd>
    <dd><div class="content"></div></dd>
    <dd><div class="content"></div></dd>
    <dd><div class="content"></div></dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".faqs dl dd").first().addClass("active");
$(".faqs dl dd .content").first().addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `first-child` selector instead of `first` as:

> first() - Reduce the set of matched elements to the first in the set.

and

> :first-child - Selects all elements that are the first child of their parent.

```
$(".faqs dl dd:first-child,.faqs dl dd:first-child .content").addClass("active");
```

Comment: Thanks! the dd:first-child works but its not setting the active class to the content class

Comment: Ahh i sorted, just needed to do dd:first-child .content - thanks for your help mate! knew it would be simply when you know how - locked in teh memory bank :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use as below also:

```
 $("div[class='faqs']>dl>dd:first-child").addClass("active");
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mkd63nqn/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
$('.faqs').find('.content:first').text('found')
```

```css
.faqs {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

dd {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faqs">
  <dl>
    <dd><div class="content"></div></dd>
    <dd><div class="content"></div></dd>
    <dd><div class="content"></div></dd>
    <dd><div class="content"></div></dd>
  </dl>
</div>

<div class="faqs">
  <dl>
    <dd><div class="content"></div></dd>
    <dd><div class="content"></div></dd>
    <dd><div class="content"></div></dd>
    <dd><div class="content"></div></dd>
  </dl>
</div>

<div class="faqs">
  <dl>
    <dd><div class="content"></div></dd>
    <dd><div class="content"></div></dd>
    <dd><div class="content"></div></dd>
    <dd><div class="content"></div></dd>
  </dl>
</div>

<div class="faqs">
  <dl>
    <dd><div class="content"></div></dd>
    <dd><div class="content"></div></dd>
    <dd><div class="content"></div></dd>
    <dd><div class="content"></div></dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```